# Why is konichiwa spelled as こんにちは

Tags: learning

こにちは also reads as konichiwa

Why the extra ん

Comment: You're asking the question the wrong way round. You should be asking "Why do people spell こんにちは *konichiwa* rather than *konnichiwa*?" and the answer is "because unfortunately they don't seem to know any better"...

Answer (score 2):

It's actually konnichiwa(こんにちは）. We don't say konichiwa（こにちは）.